# Ubuntu 18.04 Cloud Image takes long time to boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, openstack, cloud, cloud-init

I Downloaded the latest Ubuntu Cloud Image of 18.0.0.4 and uploaded it to our Openstack Instance. Whenever an instance of this image is booted it takes 10-15 minutes to finally show a console. I've tried the noresume  option in grub without success. Any idea how to figure out what is going on?

This seems to happen only when the instance does not have access to the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once your machine is up, run:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

and look at the top of the list. A likely culprit is `cloud-init`.
See [here](https://makandracards.com/operations/42688-how-to-remove-cloud-init-from-ubuntu).